# XCode doesn't generate fetched properties together with attributes and relationships when you create NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectmodel

When you create your NSManagedObject subclass from data model, XCode  generates your class with all defined attributes and relationships, but doesn't include fetched properties.

As far as I remember it wasn't an issue in older versions of XCode. Sure, I can define my fetched property manually, like it was done by previous versions of XCode:

MySubclass.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fetchedProperty;
```

MySubclass.m

```
@dynamic fetchedProperty;
```

But if XCode stopped doing it, then maybe there is an alternative way to access fetched properties. I wonder why did they change class generating behaviour and how I suppose to access fetched properties now?

Comment: What version of Xcode you're using? 9 or greater?

Comment: I use both current release version 8.1 and 9 beta.